# Infinitely Blue Shifted Light

Tags: optics

If we sent a short pulse of light bouncing between two mirrors far apart where one mirror was vibrating such that when the pulse was incident on it the light was doppler shifted - would the light keep blue shifting indefinitely?

Practically, the mirror would cease to be a mirror above some frequency of course

Comment: If you could somehow keep from losing any of the light pulse on each subsequent round trip, then sure, why not? The ever increasing energy  comes from _you_ each time you push the mirror against the momentum of the light pulse.

Comment: When you say "Practically, the mirror would cease to be a mirror above some frequency of course", I assume you are talking about the frequency of the light and yes it would eventually become an x-ray and pass right through the mirror.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities here, which affect the outcome. In both cases we are assuming completely ideal scenarios. There is no energy loss in transmission or reflection. The light is perfectly collimated and the pulse is very brief. The mirror is vibrating as an ideal mechanical resonator. Etc.

**First possibility: no energy added**

Every time that the light hits the vibrating mirror the mirror gives a Doppler blue shift to the light. The light also exerts pressure against the mirror. Energy is transferred from the mirror to the light.

When this happens the frequency of the oscillation decreases slightly. So the next reflection occurs at a slightly earlier phase of the oscillation. As this continues the system reaches the point where the light arrives at the peak of the mechanical deflection.

Beyond this point the reverse can happen, the light will redshift losing EM energy and transferring it back to the mirror. This will cause the system to oscillate about the peak deflection. Blueshifting to push the system beyond the peak and then redshifting to bring the system back under the peak. It will form a dynamic equilibrium about the peak deflection.

**Second possibility: energy added**

Alternatively, if the right amount of mechanical energy is added back to the vibrating mirror from some external source, then the phase can be kept constant. Energy would steadily be transferred from the external source, to the mirror, and to the EM waves. With everything ideal this could blueshift the light indefinitely.